# Which OBD II adapter to buy?

Tags: honda, obd-ii, hyundai

I am thinking of purchasing an OBD-II adapter, that I can pair with my android phone.
I would like to be able to use it on different cars.

Is it advisable to go for something like the [PLX Kiwi](http://plxdevices.com/product_info.php?id=GSSTBLUETOOTH), which is kind of costly, or get a generic one off Amazon for maybe 20$?

Comment: What would you like to do with this? Show you some data over PID can even the cheap one. Some other stuff like ECU error and so one you need a better one + some special software,

Comment: Remember too, you can get adapters which can read air bags and anti-lock brake fault codes as well. I would highly suggest you get one which can do these as well, whatever brand you settle on. While it will cost a little more, it will be worth it to you in the end.

Comment: I wanted an adapter to get engine information on my phone, so that I can analyse my driving. I do not want anything specific to a particular manufacturer, as I would be driving different cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that Torque recommends one of those $70 adapters, but I bought a generic one from the [Chinese equivalent of Amazon](http://www.dhgate.com/) for $20 and it's working just fine.

Comment: Well, I was driving over the weekend, and I tried out an adapter which looks like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Wirless-Diagnostic-Reader-Scanner-Iphone/dp/B00AOIM2CC), borrowed from a friend, paired with Torque Pro. It worked on one car, and on another car, it could not connect to the ECU. Still not sure where the problem is, for the connection to that car.

Comment: Usually it's the OBD header that's wrong/not supported. Other times the car is just too old and doesn't support OBD2.

Comment: This was a 2004 Hyundai(India). The other car on which I was able to connect to the ECU was a 2010 Honda

Comment: I had the same thing with a 2001 and 2005 Astra G. The 2001 wouldn't connect but the 2005 could. It also wouldn't connect to a 2006 Corsa B. It could possibly be the cheap connector, but I wouldn't wager money on it.

Comment: I bought this and it works well: http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B001LHVOVK though it's not an advanced type

Answer (score 1):

The latest offerings of OB2 to Android can be a useful quick look tool. With an Elm 327 interface to the diagnostic plug, and software such as Torgue Pro, they will give you fault codes and simulated gauges. iOBD2 is another good offering, and is supplied with specific software for specific vehicle makes. They do not go anywhere near in performance and range to garage repair equipment, so you should not lavish money on them, but rather treat them as a useful gadget. 'Swiss Army knife' springs to mind.

Comment: I ordered an adapter off Tmart, for just $10; will have to try it out. If the adapter is able to connect to the ECU and give me some PIDs, I would be more than happy, using it with Torque and it's plugins available. p.s. I still haven't explored Torque fully.